# printf unicode 7 characters from bash

Tags: bash, fonts, unicode

I am on Ubuntu 20.04. I want to print [this](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F5E0/) symbol from bash and I tried `printf "\u1F5E0"` but it didn't work. Is this supposed to work or I have font packages missing? Please advise on what I should do.

Comment: `printf '%x\n' "'"` ... `printf '%b\n' \\U1f5e0` ... `printf '%b\n' \\U$(printf '%x\n' "'")`

Comment: @bac0n Thank you this worked for me.

Comment: Replacing u with U seems to be sufficient: `printf "\U1F5E0"`

Comment: `u` is for one to four digits, and `U` is for one to eight digits... using a specifier is good practice, a string containing a specifier may interfere with the output.

Comment: @bac0n please consider making your comment(s) into an answer

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this (with an uppercased **U**) ?

`printf "\U1f5e0"` or `echo -e "\U1f5e0"`

This should work depending on your bash locale ( `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` or `LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8` ) which can be set in your .bashrc configuration file or your script.

Here is what the `man bash` page says :

```
        Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape se‐
       quences, if present, are decoded as follows:
              \a     alert (bell)
              \b     backspace
              \e
              \E     an escape character
              \f     form feed
              \n     new line
              \r     carriage return
              \t     horizontal tab
              \v     vertical tab
              \\     backslash
              \'     single quote
              \"     double quote
              \?     question mark
              \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three octal digits)
              \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)
              \uHHHH the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
              \UHHHHHHHH
                     the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
              \cx    a control-x character

       The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.

       A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign ($"string") will cause the string to be translated according to the current locale.  If the current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar
       sign is ignored.  If the string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.
```